# transform dataframe to dataframe with continuous index and columns

Tags: python, pandas

let's assume that we have the following data frame **p**

```
x    1     2     5
y                 
1  0.5  0.00  0.25
3  0.0  0.25  0.00
```

As you can see the x values are missing the values 3,4 and the y values are missing the value 2 in order for the column and index names to be continuous.
As I want to plot the array via imshow, I need extend the dataframe **p** by the missing values, resulting in:

```
x    1     2  3  4     5
y                       
1  0.5  0.00  0  0  0.25
2  0.0  0.00  0  0  0.00
3  0.0  0.25  0  0  0.00
```

I can achieve this by writing custom functions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_columns_continuous(p):
    for val in range(p.columns.min(),p.columns.max()):
        if val not in p.columns:
            p[val] = 0
            
    p = p.sort_values(by=p.columns.name,axis=1)
    return p

def make_rows_continuous(p):
    for val in range(p.index.min(),p.index.max()):
        if val not in p.index:
            s = pd.Series([0]*len(p.columns), index=p.columns, name=val)
            p = p.append(s)
            
    p = p.sort_values(by=p.index.name,axis=0)
    return p

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,2,5],'y':[1,1,3,1]})

p = pd.crosstab(df.y,df.x,normalize=True)

#creates the data frame
#x    1     2     5
#y                 
#1  0.5  0.00  0.25
#3  0.0  0.25  0.00 


p = make_columns_continuous(p)
p = make_rows_continuous(p)

#yields:
#x    1     2  3  4     5
#y                       
#1  0.5  0.00  0  0  0.25
#2  0.0  0.00  0  0  0.00
#3  0.0  0.25  0  0  0.00
```

Is there a better way to achieve this transformation? Are there even built-in pandas functions? Something like DataFrame to sparse matrix?

Comment: look at reindex, `p.reindex(range(p.index.min(),p.index.max()+1),fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to create a new DataFrame of the final size you want, and then fill it with the data from `p`:

```
p.columns = p.columns.astype(int)
newrows = range(p.index.min(), p.index.max()+1)
newcols = range(p.columns.min(), p.columns.max()+1)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=newrows, columns=newcols, data=0)

#    1  2  3  4  5
# 1  0  0  0  0  0
# 2  0  0  0  0  0
# 3  0  0  0  0  0

df.loc[p.index, p.columns] = p

#      1     2  3  4     5
# 1  0.5  0.00  0  0  0.25
# 2  0.0  0.00  0  0  0.00
# 3  0.0  0.25  0  0  0.00
```

Comment: Wow, that is a pretty easy and brilliant way of doing it! Thanks a lot. I was not aware that fitting a dataframe onto another dataframe is that easy using index and columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reindex` to fill in missing rows **and columns** (thanks for the suggestion by [Shubham Sharma!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma)):

```
p.columns = p.columns.astype(int) # I needed to explicitly convert to numeric
newrows = range(p.index.min(), p.index.max()+1)
newcols = range(p.columns.min(), p.columns.max()+1)

p.reindex(index=newrows, columns=newcols, fill_value=0)
```

In my original answer, I thought you could only use `reindex` for rows, so I had done this double transpose.  This works but is simply worse given the functionality of `reindex`

```
p = p.reindex(newrows).T.reindex(newcols).T.fillna(0)
```

Comment: You can `reindex` both rows and columns in  one go like `p.reindex(newrows, newcols, fill_value=0)` :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma :0 that is a better answer!  Will you post it?

Comment: Please feel free to edit/update your post with the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! reindex is really useful.